# R: how to use lapply or for to loop over all values of multiple strings

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a dataset with one variable categorized according to 200 alphabetic codes `code1<-c("AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE","FFF")`, 2 alphabetic codes `code2<-c("Yyy","Zzzzz")`, and 41 numeric codes `code3<-seq(1970,2011,1)`.

I have a function that produces a 8-number vector from each subset of the data according to unique values of `code1`,`code2`,`code3`. So, I would like to run a few lines of code on each subset of these data.

The complete list is imported as a data frame `data`, and I currently work by extracting each subset of the data from the data frame, analyzing it, and then saving the output

The problem is that it would be cumbersome to loop through all the values of `code1` and `code2` and `code3` according to this scheme, and it would be much better to produce a single output data frame as well, with the 8 numbers saved alongside the unique values of `code1`, `code2`, and `code3` which produced them.

I'm sure that this could be done without resorting to loops over values of code1-code3 and `assign()`, but being a neophyte I'm afraid I can't quite put it together.

Thanks -- E

Additional data:

This is what the output vector from the function I am running looks like, manually subset for one series:

```
output1<-fxn(data$input,[which(data$code1=='AAA'&data$code2=='Yyy'&data$code3==1990)])
output2<-fxn2(output1)
str(output2$out[,2]): num [1:8] 0.009 0.648 0.304 0.004 0.445 ... 
output2$out[,2]: [1] 0.009 0.648 0.304 0.004 0.445 36.720 0.000 1.103
```

Additional data:

In response to requests, this faked output dataset approximates what I'm looking for-- each row of the file is from one completed run of the function `fxn2`. The first 8 columns are output by the function; the last 3 columns are added to distinguish unique values of `code1`,`code2`,`code3`:

```
> head(data)
   X.x1    x2    x3    x4    x5     x6 x7    x8 code3 code2 code1
1 0.008 0.595 0.185 0.005 0.173 36.744  0 1.102 1970  male  BGR
2 0.004 0.242 0.276 0.005 0.348 46.017  0 1.108 1971  male  BGR
3 0.002 0.553 0.242 0.005 0.247 35.424  0 1.107 1972  male  BGR
4 0.005 0.593 0.270 0.004 0.312 43.701  0 1.105 1973  male  BGR
5 0.009 0.660 0.217 0.005 0.266 37.955  0 1.103 1974  male  BGR
6 0.006 0.347 0.297 0.005 0.411 50.959  0 1.108 1975  male  BGR
> dput(head(data))
structure(list(X.x1 = c(0.008, 0.004, 0.002, 0.005, 0.009, 0.006
), x2 = c(0.595, 0.242, 0.553, 0.593, 0.66, 0.347), x3 = c(0.185, 
0.276, 0.242, 0.27, 0.217, 0.297), x4 = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.004, 0.005, 0.005), x5 = c(0.173, 0.348, 0.247, 0.312, 0.266, 
0.411), x6 = c(36.744, 46.017, 35.424, 43.701, 37.955, 50.959
), x7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x8 = c(1.102, 1.108, 1.107, 1.105, 
1.103, 1.108), year = 1970:1975, sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "male", class = "factor"), iso3 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "BGR", class = "factor")), .Names = c("X.x1", 
"x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "year", "sex", "iso3"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Do you want to run your functions for all combinations of code1, code2 and code3 values?

Comment: Hi, yes-- that's right. In the end I do want to run the function once for each unique combination of code1,code2,code3.

Comment: Can you give `dput(head(data))` and `head()` of what the intended ouput should be?

Comment: Hi, Hugh-- I've done that and the output is shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code by doing this. If you give more details about desired output, I will update the answer accordingly.

```
code1<-c("AAA","BBB","DDD","EEE","FFF")
code2<-c("Yyy","Zzzzz")
code3<-seq(1970,2011,1) 
params <- expand.grid(code1, code2, code3)
names(params) <- c('code1', 'code2', 'code3')

myFunc <- function(code1, code2, code3) {
    ##add your function code here.
  ...
  ...
  return(output2$out[,2])
}

    LL <- mapply(FUN=myFunc, code1 = params$code1, code2 = params$code2, code3 = params$code3)
    result <- split(LL, rep(1:ncol(LL), each = nrow(LL)))
    result <- do.call(rbind, result)
    result <- cbind(result, params)         result <- cbind(result, params)
```

Comment: This is definitely a useful start. Inside of myFunc, how would I set it to append output from each run of the subroutine to an appropriately named output object?

Comment: @iisan7  can you also show what `output2$out[,2]` looks like. Answer will depend on that

Comment: > str(output2$out[,2]):  num [1:8] 0.009 0.648 0.304 0.004 0.445 ... > > output2$out[,2]: [1]  0.009  0.648  0.304  0.004  0.445 36.720  0.000  1.103

Comment: @iisan7  that should help you get started

Comment: Excellent. I had to make a minor modification: result<-split(LL, rep(1:ncol(LL), each = nrow(LL))) and then result <- do.call(rbind, result) and then result<cbind(result,params). What is the etiquette-- should I edit your reply and then mark the answer?

Comment: @iisan7  sure go ahead